# Error ao tentar instalar yowsup: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio, whatsapp

Estou tentando instalar um aplicativo que realiza o registro de celulares no *Whatsapp*.
Eu tentei usar o  comando abaixo:

```
python setup.py install
```

E ocorre o seguinte erro:

> error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

Alguem sabe por que acontece este erro?
Agradeço desde já pelas respostas.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required, já tentou instalá-lo?

Comment: já esta instalado tenho sql server e o visual studio , e já verifiquei que já se encontra instalado o visual c++ 10.0 não  sei o motivo do erro ainda

Comment: Se o Visual Studio já está instalado, verifique se está acessível por linha de comando. Abra um terminal e digite "vcvarsall.bat". Se a mensagem for de comando não encontrado, procure no seu computador por este arquivo e adicione o diretório na variável de sistema PATH. Abs!

Comment: Ok @FernandoMacedo irei tentar fazer isso. Obrigado

Comment: @JacobdeOliveira Tenho um post sobre como instalar o Python no Windows e configurar um compilador, pode ser que ajude: http://fernandomacedo.com/programacao/instalando-python-no-windows/

Comment: okay vou verificar o site obrigado @FernandoMacedo!

Comment: funcionou @FernandoMacedo coloquei vcvarsall.bat no path e funcionou muito obrigado :)

Comment: @JacobdeOliveira Posso colocar como resposta vc marca como a resposta certa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o Visual Studio já está instalado, verifique se está acessível por linha de comando.

Abra um terminal e digite:

```
vcvarsall.bat
```

Se a mensagem for de comando não encontrado, procure no seu computador por este arquivo e adicione o diretório na variável de sistema `PATH`.

Tenho um post sobre como instalar o Python no Windows e configurar um compilador, pode ser que ajude: http://fernandomacedo.com/programacao/instalando-python-no-windows